# Добавление кнопок на Google Map Android

Tags: android, google-maps-api, java

Нужно сделать перемещение по карте кнопками, может кто то подсказать как такое сделать, ни одного туториала по этому вопросу не нашел, и как юзать вообще такое я не представляю. Карту на телефоне вывел, теперь нужно добавить по нажатию на кнопку ехать или вверх или вниз или вправо или влево. Есть у кого нибудь примеры? Или хотя бы скажите какое событие и как перемещать карту?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == btn4) {
            GeoPoint p = mapView.getMapCenter();
            GeoPoint z = new GeoPoint(p.getLatitudeE6(), p.getLongitudeE6() - 1000000);
            mc.animateTo(z);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Используй `RelativeLayout`, чтобы разместить свои кнопки поверх `MapView`, и `mapView.getController().scrollBy(x, y)`, чтобы двигать карту:

```
...
onClick(View v) {
    if (v == mMyCustomPanLeftButton) {
        mMapController.scrollBy(-15 /*x*/, 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Оно карту листает, но не обновляет вместо карты черный экран

Comment: не обновляет, потому что ему связь с инетом нужна, это же онлайн карта. тогда будет обновлять.

Comment: Т.е. изначально карта показывается, а потом по клику превращается в прямоугольник малевича, или карта черная сразу? Попробуй дернуть mMapView.postInvalidate() после scrollBy(), возможно, починится.

Comment: Нет когда листаешь, доходит только до момента где загружено, а дальше не погружается карта, я попробовал сделать через animateTo это удобней способ, но там больше нужно делать в плане логики

Comment: Хм.. да, через animateTo определенно будет сложнее. Попробуй invalidate() дернуть (хотя наверняка пробовал уже)

Comment: Пробовал) Не помогло)

Answer (score 0):

Может, что-то из класса com.google.android.maps.MapController подойдет?

Comment: а поточней можно? пожалуйста

Comment: Поточнее не получится, т.к. я этим ни разу не занимался и это всего лишь предположение. Вот [описание класса][1] - можно методом научного тыка попытаться дойти.

[1]: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapController

Comment: там нету того что нужно.